# human input in system dialog without knowledge - is is possible to "recall"?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, gmail

While I was writing email in Gmail (Ubuntu 10.10, Firefox 7) suddenly I got popup (not website, dialog box (like system/browser).
I was just pressing space, so dialog box got submitted by default choice (enter==space for submitting probably "OK" or "CANCEL" message).

I'm bit afraid. I've just submitted dialog box without ANY knowledge about it. It could have been something not important,however it could have been something important like preference confirmation.
Is there any way to find out ? Some logfile logging this stuff (I didn't find any) ?